# ASP.net website project cannot connect to local SQL Server 2008 Express instance

Tags: asp.net, sql, connection-string

I need to connect a SQL Server 2008 database to an asp.net website project.  Here's the connection string in my web.config file:

```
<add name="sqlConnectionString" 
     connectionString="data source=.\MSSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I can log on the server and database with SSMS, but when I try to build the website I always got the error msg below:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection
>   string is not valid)]

I searched on internet and tried to enable TCP and started sql browser etc, but still getting the same error message.  I'm banging my head against the wall now.  Please help.  Many thanks.

Comment: and the connection string is ... ??

Comment: sorry, here's the line in web.config:  <add name="sqlConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\MSSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database was attached through SSMS, you should be able to connect to it with something like this:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=<dbname>;Trusted_Connection=True;
```